# Partition RDD in Apache Spark such that one partition consists on one file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, bigdata

I am creating a single RDD of 2.csv files like this

```
val combineRDD = sc.textFile("D://release//CSVFilesParellel//*.csv")
```

Then I want to define custom partition on this RDD such that one partition must contain one file.
so that each partition i.e.one csv file is processed across one node for faster data processing

Is it possible to write a custom partitioner based on the file size or the number of lines in one file or the end of file character of one file ?

How do I achieve this ?

The structure of one file looks something like this:

00-00

Time(in secs)  Measure1  Measure2  Measure3..... Measuren

0

0.25

0.50

0.75

1

...

3600

---

1.The first row of data contains the hours: mins 
    Each file contains data for 1 hour or 3600secs

2.The first column is a second divided into 4 parts of 250 ms each and data recorded for 250 ms

3. For every file I want to add the number of hours: mins to the seconds so that my time looks something like this hours-mins-secs. But the catch is I dont want this process to happen sequentially
4. I am using  the for-each function for getting each file name -> then creating an RDD of the data in the file and adding the time as specified above.
5. But what I want is that **every file** should go to one node for processing and calculating time as opposed **to data in one file** getting distributed across nodes for calculating the time.

Thank you.

Regards,

Vinay Joglekar

Comment: I can't think of anything different from the function `wholeTextFiles`. I mean, in theory you could create a partitioner that is based on the filename, but from my understanding, this is something like what `wholeTextFiles` does.

Comment: But wholeTextFiles does not preserve the columns in the file. It will create a string of all the data I dont want that.

Comment: well, you want to parse .csv files then. For this you could use https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv . Have you tried it yet?

Comment: The parsing part comes afterward first I would like to partition data such that one partition contains one file

Comment: Why do you want this? Could you please explain the problem you are trying to solve this way. I have a feeling that you are on a wrong path here.

Comment: I have edited the my original post citing what I wish to do.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input file and what is the output that you want from it ! @VinayJoglekar

Answer (score 1):

Lets go back to basics.

1. Philosphy of BigData move Process to the data and not data to process. this way one increases parallelism and hence I/O throughput
2. One partitioner taking one file will decrease the parallelism not increase.
3. Simplest way to achieve this is use textInpuTFormat and have your input files compresses by gzip or lzo( no lzo indexing should be done).
4. Gzip being non splittable will force one file going to one partition but this in no way will help in anyKind throughput increase
5. To Write Custom Input Format Extend from FileInputFormat and give your splitlogic  and recordReader logic.

To use custom input format in spark please follow

> http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/combineparquetfileinputformat/

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer without questioning why you're doing this. Load the files separately so you know the filename being loaded

```
// create firstRDD containing a new attribute `filename=first.csv`
val firstRDD = sc.textFile("D://release//CSVFilesParellel//first.csv")
    .map(line => new CsvRecord(line))

// create secondRDD containing a new attribute `filename=second.csv`
val secondRDD = sc.textFile("D://release//CSVFilesParellel//second.csv")
    .map(line => new CsvRecord(line))

// now create a pair RDD and re-partition on the filename
val partitionRDD = firstRDD.union(secondRDD)
    .map(csvRecord => (csvRecord.filename,csvRecord))
    .partitionBy(customFilenamePartitioner)
```

The following quote from [here](https://intellipaat.com/tutorial/spark-tutorial/working-with-keyvalue-pairs/)

> To implement your customFilenamePartitioner, you need to subclass the
>   org.apache.spark.Partitioner class and implement three types of
>   methods :
>
> NumPartitions : Int, which returns the number of partitions that you will create it as per the requirements.
>
> getPartition(key: Any) : Int, which returns the partition ID ranging
>   from (0 to numPartitions-1) for a given key.
>
> equals(), : the standard Java programming equality method. This is
>   important to implement because Spark application will need to test
>   your Partitioner object against other instances by its own terms when
>   it decides whether two of your RDDs are partitioned the same way as it
>   is required.

Keep in mind that a repartition will most likely trigger an expensive shuffle, so unless you are going to be repeatedly querying this newly partitioned RDD you may be better off solving your problem another way.